# is this a correct way to do Elasticsearch performance test?

Tags: elasticsearch

I`m doing a performance test with 2 queries, based on some requirement.

Below are the hardware/software env I`m using.

```
CPU 8core
Memory 16G
OS centOS 7
elasticsearch 2.1
8G memory for ES heap
no swap
```

The requirements is that

```
all query response time less 3 seconds.
```

The map I use is like below:

```
"@timestamp": { "index": "not_analyzed", "type": "date","format": "epoch_second"},
"ROUTER" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"IN_IFACE" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"OUT_IFACE" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"SRC_MAC" : { "type" : "long", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"DST_MAC" : { "type" : "long", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"IP_PAIRE" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"SRC_IP" : { "type" : "ip", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"DST_IP" : { "type" : "ip", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"SRC_PORT" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"DST_PORT" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed"},
"VLAN" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
"PROTOCOL" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
"BYTES" : { "type" : "long", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
"PACKETS" : { "type" : "long", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
```

The query are:

```
curl -XPOST "127.0.0.1:9200/sflow_1454256000/sflow/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "size":0,
    "query": {
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{
                "range": { "@timestamp": {"gte":0,"lte":1554258400}}
            }
        }
    },
  "aggs":
    {
      "SRC_DST":
        {
          "terms": {"script": "[doc.SRC_IP.value, doc.DST_IP.value].join(\"-\")","size": 2,"shard_size":0, "order": {"sum_bits": "desc"}},
          "aggs": { "sum_bits": { "sum": {"field": "BYTES"} } }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XPOST "127.0.0.1:9200/sflow_1454256000/sflow/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "size":0,
    "query": {
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{
                "range": { "@timestamp": { "gte":0,"lte":1554258400}}
            }
        }
    },
  "aggs":
    {
      "SRC_MAC":
        {
          "terms": {"field":"SRC_MAC", "size": 3,"shard_size":0, "order": {"sum_bits": "desc"}},
          "aggs": { "sum_bits": { "sum": {"field": "BYTES"} } }
        }
    }
}'
```

Based on the offical docs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/capacity-planning.html). First you need to find out the max number of docs for one shard. Then find out how many shards your computer can hold.

Below are my steps:

First, I use only one shard for one index in my node.

```
When the shard have 40 000 docs , response time is 3s.
```

Then I know that in my environment,

**the limit for one shard is 40 000 docs if I want the response time within 30s**

Based on this, I use multiple shards to run those two queries. Each shard contains 40 000 docs. The result is :

```
When the number of shards is 2 (each shard have 400 000 docs), the response time is 3s.
```

Then I get the conclusion that,

**the limit for my computer is 2 shards, each have 400 000 docs(totaly 800 000 docs). If I want the response time within 3s.**

**So, Could you help to point out if I`m doing the test in a wrong way?**

**Also, I do not have much experience in using ES. So is it a reasonable test result given my hardware/software environment and the 3s response requirement?**

------------------update-------------

I actually did some other test too. I use 5 shards, totaly contains 900 000 docs. (Means 180 000 docs per shard). The response time actually better than the 2 shard, 800 000 docs way. So I think this proved that my previous conclusion is wrong. But I`m doing the test based on the offical docs advise. Can any one tell me why?

The offical documents link that I`m doing my test based on. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/capacity-planning.html

Comment: Upvoting to move this question to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi Sameer, This is not a code review. More like a plan review. Thanks:) Is there any section about plan review?

Comment: Not really. You can stick to Stack Overflow or use Code Review. Both would suffice I guess. The moderators probably can take a call here.

Comment: There might be more chances to get an answer on SO (there are only [3 questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) about elasticsearch on CR and most of the answers address the program using it)

Comment: I do not think my question is tough here... But seems no one answering it. Can you gays give some suggestion like making more people note about this post?